# Duplicating Google MapView fragment for different purpose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

I have a list view with three items on a fragment  and on itemClick of first item it replaces with next fragment containing mapView.(the mapView has marker placed at one location). Now my problem is: while clicking the second or third item of list view, how can I use the same MapView fragment to display the map with marker at different position ? This is my MapViewFragment:

```
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;




    public MapViewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_view, container, false);
        return mView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);

        if (mMapView != null){
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        }
    }

    //method of OnMapReadyCallBack Interface


    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(27.619619, 85.538637))
                .title("Kathmandu University Dhulikhel Kavre")
                .snippet("Detalis here")
        );

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(27.619619, 85.538637);

        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapInfoItem(getActivity().getLayoutInflater()));

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



    }
}
```

And ItemClickListener for listviews:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new MapViewFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();


                        break;
                    case 1:
//what do I do here
                    case 2:
//what do I do here




                }



            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you mean that each item needs to display a different marker on the map? In that case you don't need to replace the fragment at all. Just remove and place a new marker

Comment: @vlatkozelka does that mean create another fragment with marker at different location?

Comment: No, the exact opposite. Create the map fragment at the beginning, outside the click listener itself. When you click on an item in the list, create a marker and put it on the map, when you click another, remove the first marker and place another.

Comment: @vlatkozelka can you please expain me with a example?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one fragment or activity holding both MapFragment and listView. All you need to do is get access to the map object, and add/remove markers on click. You already have most of it done.

```
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;




    public MapViewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_view, container, false);
        return mView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);

        if (mMapView != null){
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        }
    }

    //method of OnMapReadyCallBack Interface


    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(27.619619, 85.538637))
                .title("Kathmandu University Dhulikhel Kavre")
                .snippet("Detalis here")
        );

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(27.619619, 85.538637);

        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapInfoItem(getActivity().getLayoutInflater()));

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



    }

 //Add this method to get access to the map from outside the fragment
 public GoogleMap getGoogleMap(){
    return mGoogleMap;
 }
}
```

Now inside the parent activity/fragment where you have you click listener, first place the fragment by calling :

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new MapViewFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

inside the Activity onCreate() or the framgent onCreateView

Then inside the click listener that you wrote, keep the same map, just replace the marker:

```
 Marker marker;// keep a reference to your marker

 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                gotoLocation1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                 gotoLocation2();
                    break;
                case 2:
                 gotoLocation3();
                    break;
          }
    });

  private void gotoLocation1(){
   GoogleMap googleMap = youMapFragment.getGoogleMap();
            if(googleMap == null){
             return; // your map might not have loaded yet
            }

            if(marker != null)
               marker.remove();

   googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(27.619619, 85.538637))
            .title("Kathmandu University Dhulikhel Kavre")
            .snippet("Detalis here")
    );

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(27.619619, 85.538637);

    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapInfoItem(getActivity().getLayoutInflater()));

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));
}

// now do the same for gotoLocation2() and gotoLlocation3() just chaning the lat lng

  }
```